# babel not rendering Arabic font correctly

Tags: babel, arabic

I have an Arabic font (Traditional Arabic), but babel is not rendering it correctly, it leaves gaps between the letters (they should be connected):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Traditional Arabic}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\Large
رَسُولُ ٱللَّهِ وَكَلِمَتُهُ أَلْقَىٰهَا إِلَى مَرْيَمَ وَرُوحٌ مِّنْهُ
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix it please?

[image]

Comment: Try with the Harfbuzz renderer, ie, `\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Traditional Arabic}`.

Comment: Please put this as answer so that I accept it.